# What is happening in my console when running this code?

Tags: python, while-loop, console

I want a loop that will ask to for a number. When the number is inside the right range I want this loop to stop.
Here is my code with a class Player. The take_guess method is giving me troubles.

```
import random
class Player:
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name
    self.score = 0

class Game:
  def __init__(self):
    self.secret_number = 0
    self.player = None

  def gen_number(self,lower,upper):
    self.secret_number = random.randint(lower,upper)
    self.lower = lower
    self.upper = upper

  def take_guess(self):
    while True:
      guess = int(input(f"Enter your guess between {self.lower} and {self.upper}: "))
      if self.lower <= guess <= self.upper:
        break
      else:
        print("Invalid guess! Please enter a number within the specified range.")
        
  
first_game = Game()
first_game.gen_number(1,20)
first_game.take_guess()
second_game = Game()
```

What is happening in the console?

[image]

Comment: the code is working fine while running via linux terminal, how are you running the code?

Comment: your conversion to an int your be inside a try / catch block, so you can capture exceptions when you input strings that cannot be converted to integers.

Comment: After you input 8 the program will terminate

Answer (score 0):

The unpredictable behaviour you are seeing is due to your use of the [break statement](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue). By using it the way you have, you are completely exiting the `while True:` loop and ending up in an essentially unknown part of your code. Instead, try using the `continue` keyword, which will jump back up to the top of your while loop, or simply leave it; your `else` will handle when input is outside the expected range just fine.

Comment: Would it be better to add a `return guess`  so I can stop the `while` loop when entering a valid number?

Comment: Yes that would be a good simple way to handle this issue

Answer (score 0):

your code run fine.

you are currently working in python shell, code execution is done complete without any error.

you are now typing things in the python shell. for that you can see result for `8, 100, "HDc"`

now for input `notHDR` which you are typing in the python shell, it is not a string,python is considering it as a object. this object is not defined in the codebase or in shell object local.

because of this you are getting this `Nameerror`

Answer (score 0):

you input a space or tab, not a digital number,so it output error
so you should add a try catch like this:

```
  def take_guess(self):
    while True:
      input_right = True
      num = 0
      guess = 0
      while input_right:
        try:
            kk = input(f"Enter your guess between {self.lower} and {self.upper}: ")
            guess = int(kk)
        except:
            print("input again, not digital number", kk)
            num += 1
            if num > 10:
                print("too many error, exit.")
                exit(-1)
            continue
        input_right = False
      if self.lower <= guess <= self.upper:
        break
      else:
        print("Invalid guess! Please enter a number within the specified range.")
```